# Node needing to get access to row => or clone it , yet it doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, sql-server, node.js, node-modules, arrow-functions

I switched to using the Node JS  mssql tedious drivers with the STREAM.

The arrow syntax is throwing me off big time with scope and the loops etc...

1. I am successful in taking the 1st query result and then appending nested data to it.  However this make no sense to me

   ```
   request.on('row', row => {     // so "row" is object of data in scope but how to access?

    console.log(row); // I see that I am giving it to spit out the records on each loop
    obj = extend({}, row);   // this was a hail mary move to try to copy the object from more of a global object declaration.
   ```

Problem is the `request.on('row', row => {`   is a loop that is isolated  :/

SOOO , what I want to do it RETURN THAT FINISHED recordset of "row"  ...

I have this code

```
  request.on('done', results => { 
        //  this code cannot see  "row" 

       before the arrow function etc... , I would return my data with

       res.json(mydata); // how I did in the past 
  });
```

[image]

**Complete code**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var sql = require('mssql');
    var xconfig = require('../../config.js');
    var newConfig = xconfig.database.liberty;
    var extend = require('util')._extend;

    exports.getLibScriptQuestions = function (connection, req, res) {
        //console.log('conn',connection);

        const poolLiberty = new sql.ConnectionPool(newConfig, err => {
            var obj = "";
            var responseData = [];

            var request = new sql.Request(poolLiberty);
            request.stream = true;
            var query = 'SELECT * FROM ' +
                ' dbo.vwScriptQuestions vwsq';

            request.query(query);

            request.on('recordset', columns => {
                // emit once

            });

            request.on('row', row => {


                var requestOD = new sql.Request(poolLiberty);
                requestOD.input('QuestionId', sql.Int, row.QuestionId);
                var sqlquery = 'SELECT q.id AS QuestionId, d.* FROM ' +
                    ' Scripts.Question q ' +
                    ' JOIN Scripts.QustionDirectiveAssoc qda ON q.Id = qda.QuestionId' +
                    ' JOIN Scripts.Directives d on qda.DirectiveId = d.Id ' +
                    ' WHERE q.Id = @QuestionId';
                requestOD.query(sqlquery, (err, result) => {
                    row.directives = result.recordset;
                    //console.log('row', row)


                   //console.log(row.directives[0].Tag);
                   obj = row.directives[0].Tag;
                    //obj.push(row.directives);
                    //obj = extend({}, row.directives);
                    responseData.push(row);

                    //console.log(result.recordset);
                    //console.log('directives',row.directives);
                });
                //console.log(row);
                //

            })

            request.on('error', err => {
                // May be emitted multiple times
                console.log('err', err);
            })



            request.on('done', result => {
                console.log('done x records', result);

                console.log('request',request.query.recordsets);

                console.log(responseData);
                console.log('obj', obj)
                //res.json(vm);
                res.json(responseData);

            })


        })

        sql.on('error', err => {
            console.log('err happened', err);
        })

    }

}());
```

Comment: Just to understand better. Instead of work on each row at a time, you want to access all of the returned data when the request is finished. Is that the case?

Comment: YES.    I know that the data is "there"  but how do I access it to send back?

Comment: `request.on('done', result => {    console.log(result) })`   ....

Comment: Above line outputs  this     `{ output: {}, rowsAffected: [ 3 ] }`   which yes there are 3 records ,  but  ouptput empty ?

Comment: So, it seems that you don't want, nor need, to use the streaming interface. You will be probably better just using `execute` and working on the `recordsets` returned from it. Check it here: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#execute-procedure-callback

Comment: I was using the streaming because my boss switched to that in order to not have connection issues..  he was saying to modify his... but he takes data from sql server,  that loops over records adding in nested objects and writes it out immediately to mongodb ...  something he prefers for logs and billing etc...      but yes  I was using the other style just fine ... until I needed to add some data to each row  ( 1 to many relationship) for a nice json object to consume in angular etc...

Comment: So the ability to loop over the data and then say    row.directives = result.recordset  ...   which is essentially appending object to an object on every row based on the query with each unique questionId  etc

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see `streaming` helping with connections issues. Try to take a look at how `connections` are handled by `node-mssql`: https://github.com/patriksimek/node-mssql#connect-callback. But i don't know about your structure, so can't tell much about it. I'll write a code as an answer that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you want to achieve.

```
let responseData = [];
request.on('row', row => {
    responseData.push(row);
});

request.on('done', results => {
    res.json(responseData);
});
```

Comment: And do you see some data when having `console.log('row', row)` right before `push(row)`, and a `console.log('responseData', responseData)` before `res.json`?

Comment: Yes,  for row before push(row) ,   No on the other before res.json  ,   I will update question with a screenshot   thx

Comment: the `console.log` within `'done'` event is happening after all `console.log(row)`, right? Without seeing your code i just can think that you can maybe be declaring `responseData` within a scope not reached by the `done` event.

Comment: done is down below,  based on the examples.   I even tried moving responseData around a bit  along with changing from let to var ....    odd..   i'm no javascript guru...  possible that I cannot simply push the data in like that?

Comment: Try to obfuscate some private parts of your code and post the overall structure of it. Can't help more without seeing what you are doing.

Comment: Yes,  I am thinking about looping over the data as I don't understand what the problem is.     I even declared  var obj = ""   then    `obj = row.directives[0].Tag;`  of which console.log output is fine ,  but in that arrow function it is empty    ugh

Comment: I went ahead and pasted the complete code in my question  -  maybe it makes more sense or jumps out at you ...  I appreciate your time and help Diego